# Problem with Random and Threads in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, data-structures, collections

I'm having trouble with the [Random](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx) class in .NET, I'm implementing a threaded collection which is working fine, except for one smaller detail. The collection is a [Skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list) and those of you familiar with it know that for every node inserted I need to generate a new height that is `<= CurrentMaxHeight+1`, here's the code that I'm using to do that (I know it's very inefficient, but it works and thats my main priority now)

```
int randomLevel()
{
  int height = 1;

  while(rnd.NextDouble() >= 0.5 && height < MaxHeight)
    ++height;

  return height;
}
```

My problem here is that sometimes I keep getting only 1 back from this for several thousand elements in a row which kills the performance of the skip list. The chance for 10.000 elements to generate only 1 from this method in a row, seems very slim (happens pretty consistently).

So I'm assuming *(guessing)* that there is a problem with the `Random` object in some way, but I don't really know where to start digging around. So I turn to stackoverflow to see if anyone has an idea?

**Edit**

The rnd-variable is declared in the class `SkipList<T>`, and it is accessed from several threads (each thread calls .Add on the collection and Add calls .randomLevel)

Comment: Where is `rnd` declared?

Comment: is the randomlevel() called from a separate thread?

Comment: added declaration for clarity, it's declared once and then called from several different threads.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try `lock`ing the `Random` object.

```
int RandomLevel()
{
    int height = 1;

    lock(rnd)
    {
        while(rnd.NextDouble >= 0.5 && height < MaxHeight) height++;
    }

    return height;
}
```

There may be an issue with collisions when multiple threads access the `Random` object at the same time, and the seed might be getting corrupted. I can't offer any insight into what might be *specifically* happening, but according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.random.aspx), instance members of the `Random` type are not guaranteed to be thread-safe, so a `lock` seems called for in any event.

Comment: you should lock it this way:

double d;
lock(rnd) d=rnd.NextDouble();

this is better performance

Comment: Locking the entire while loop seems a somewhat bad idea.

Comment: Benny: I'm not doubting you, but care to explain why? In my mind it would give worse performance since I need to do the lock operation several times.

Comment: The longer one thread keep lock, the longer other threads have to block

Comment: By locking the while loop, you effectively let concurrent threads wait until the loop is finished. Since the NextDouble call is expensive as is, there should be some performance gain from running Benny's code in multiple threads.

Comment: this was the problem, I wasn't locking the rnd object - silly that I missed it.

Comment: I locked the entire loop since the nature of the operation seemed like it needed to be more or less atomic. If it doesn't, then yes, you could expand it out and only lock the `NextDouble` operation.

Comment: Just curious.  Which one is more expensive?  Random.NextDouble() or Monitor.Enter() & Monitor.Exit() together with possible context switching (on multi-core CPU)?

Comment: You can have a separate instance of the Random object for each thread. For example by using the [ThreadStatic] attribute. No locking is necessary in that case.

Comment: I can confirm this behavior and the fix. In my case I was getting a random double from 0 to 1 and it was always returning 0.

Comment: Careful with [ThreadStatic].  All of the Random objects will be intialised with the same seed.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't lock the entire while loop. Just lock the rnd.NextDouble() calls.

```
int RandomLevel()
{
  int height = 1;
  double newRand;

  lock(rnd) { newRand = rnd.NextDouble(); }

  while(newRand >= 0.5 && height < MaxHeight)
  {
    height++;
    lock(rnd) { newRand = rnd.NextDouble(); }
  }

  return height;
}
```

Although if performance is a consideration, I would certainly compare both solutions, as there might be a difference in single threaded vs. multithreaded performance.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as though your loop runs less than half the time it's called - is that what you're looking for (when a random number between 0 and 1 is > 0.5? This could explain why you're getting "1" more often than you'd expect - at least half the time, it's not even running the loop that increments height - it just sets the height to 1, doesn't change it, and then returns "1". I'm not familiar with skip lists, so this might be intentional, but I thought I'd ask.

I'm not too familiar with working with random numbers, but is it possible that you've got a seeding problem? If you're not randomizing the Random object when you instantiate it, it may return a predictable stream of numbers, instead of ones that are truly random. Perhaps not causing the behavior you're seeing here, but something to consider moving forward.